# Splitting image into RGB channels with strange result

Tags: image, matlab, colors

I used MATLAB to split one image into RGB channel and export the binary RGB image, the following is the original image:

[image: The original image]

I split the image into RGB channel by the following code:

```
R = secretImg(:,:,1);
G = secretImg(:,:,2);
B = secretImg(:,:,3);

imwrite(R,'RedChannel.tif');
imwrite(G,'GreenChannel.tif');
imwrite(B,'BlueChannel.tif');
```

However, the following are the results:
[image: The result]

As you can see, in the red channel binary image, we cannot even see any colour from red component, it just show blue; In blue channel, we cannot see anything in blue component!

What happened?

Comment: White is [1,1,1], blue is [0,0,1], the blue channel is 1. You don't see a difference between 1 and 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't strange. It works as it should.

Here is a simple illustration which may be easy for you to understand

> - Pure Red    -> R-1 G-0 B-0.
> - Pure Green -> R-0 G-1 B-0.
> - Pure Blue    -> R-0 G-0 B-1.
> - White           -> R-1 G-1 B-1.
> - Black           -> R-0 G-0 B-0.
> - Gray            -> R-x G-x B-x. (x could be anything between 0-1 but same for all components)

So when you view only the red component image,  you don't see difference between white and Red color as they both holds value `1`.

Similarly you could figure out the reason for missing blue foot print in Blue component image.